# Mysql SELECT first row with value found or last row if no value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would like to select row where first value found or last row if no value found.

```
id | customer |  default_address
--------------------------------
 1     John          0
 2     Will          0
 3     David        null
 4     Joe           0
```

In this case, i would like to have row with id = 4 because there's no default_address with value 1.

```
id | customer |  default_address
--------------------------------
 1     John          0
 2     Will          1
 3     David        null
 4     Joe           0
```

In this case, i need row 2 because i need default_address with value 1.

Default address can have values 0,1 and null.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, cause i don't know where to start. I expect some subqueries maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Not so fancy, but I guess this should work and run pretty fast

```
select * from
(
  (select * from your_table where default_address = 1 order by id limit 1)
  union all
  (select * from your_table order by id desc limit 1)
) tmp
limit 1
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7626d/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a single query with conditional ordering using `CASE EXPRESSION`:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.default_address = 1 THEN t.id ELSE 999999999 end ASC,
         t.id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This way, `IF` there is a record with `default_address = 1` it will be ordered first, if not, the last `ID` will be ordered first, and then it will pick the first one using `LIMIT 1`.

Note that I used the value `999999999` in the case so it will choose the first one in case there is more then 1 row with `default_address = 1`, this number just have to be larger then your biggest `ID` in the table in order for this to work properly.

Comment: You need to order by id **asc** if there is a default_address = 1

Comment: @juergend You are right, fixed but if you know a better way then this then you are welcomed to share:)

Comment: @juergend Its already fixed, no need to downvote for a typo, was just missing the `end` part , I avoided two cases anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Sub-Query.

```
SELECT * FROM(
   (SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE default_address = 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)
   UNION ALL
  (SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY id DESC limit 1)
) tmp
limit 1
```